# After Effects is not seeing CUDA in my GTX 1060 GPU

Tags: video, after-effects

I've got this weird problem. I have the latest After Effects 2020 and this is how my "GPU Information" window looks like.

As far as I remember, this is not how it should normally be. It must have CUDA details and other options. Why are they missing?

I've spent 3 hours and still got nothing.

[image: GPU Information AE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's the wrong place. Please go to File -> Project Settings -> and into the first tab: Video and Rendering Effects. There you should find "Mercury GPU Acceleration (CUDA)" as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]